# Connect Azure Databricks with Netapp

Tags: azure, import, databricks, connector, netapp

I have some .csv files on Netapp that I would like to import into Databricks. Is there any way to accomplish this?
Alternatively, I could import the same files, but zipped, from HDFS mounting Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1.
I would highly prefer the first option.
Thanks in advance.